# JQuery/Javascript/CSS icon shrinking when de-hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have three social icons which grow when hovered (css element:hover) - I want them to shrink slowly to the initial size when user stops hovering them - how could I solve it with Javascript, CSS or jQuery?

Comment: Please past your code, of what exactly are you doing and what result you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS alone to achieve this via the `transition` property, no Javascript required.

```
.icon {
    font-size: 2em; // assuming the icons are font-based. Use height/width otherwise
    transition: font-size 0.3s;
}
.icon:hover {
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/rfp5qfcr/)

Comment: Thanks, I always placed my transitions in the :hover element so it didn't work both ways. Definitely a nice thing to know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, jQuery has a handy-dandy function set called `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` that I'm sure you've heard of :).

You obviously know how to get the elements to grow, so for them to shrink I would reverse what you've done and decrease the size after `.mouseleave()` Something like this, I think, would work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('your_element_here').on('mouseleave', function(){

        $(this).animate({height: '20px', width: '20px'}, 500);

    });

});
```

Only you'd replace the `'20px'`'s with whatever height and width you want the icon to shrink down to. I hope this helps and I would be glad to expand on this as much as you need so comment if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the exact function I was looking for. I haven't heard about it before, I'm a bit on the beginner side :)